# Use my own domain as a google sites URL with Google Apps

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, google-classic-sites

I have several Google Sites at my organization that we use for different projects and audiences.

I'm already using the feature that lets me map a subdomain of my domain to the google sites by adding a CNAME record of "ghs.google.com" -- for example, I have `project1.example.com` which redirects to `https://sites.google.com/a/example.com/project1/Home`.  After the initial redirect, though, all of the URLS are at google's domain:

- sites.google.com/a/example.com/project1/Home
- sites.google.com/a/example.com/project1/AnotherPage
- sites.google.com/a/example.com/project1/AnotherPage/Subpage

I would like the visible urls to be:

- project1.example.com/Home
- project1.example.com/AnotherPage
- project1.example.com/AnotherPage/Subpage

I'm not concerned about http vs. https.

Is there a way to do this using Google Apps?

---

*UPDATE (10/26)*

I think the problem is that this is a private google site and I require a login for people to view it.  When I temporarily published it publicly and visited without logging in, the urls mapped and displayed as I wanted.  For privacy reasons, though, this site has to be password-protected. **Do you know of any way to retain the subdomain mapping for logged-in users?**

Answer (score 5):

In the section '[Sites Outside of Google Apps](http://sites.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99448)':

- in the more actions --> manage site section
- Web Address tab
- (need ability to modify DNS CNAME info for your domain)
- Update DNS records

[Here's a video](http://www.youtube.com/v/dFdPjUj1aUg) too.

Comment: +1 didn't know you could do this, have just been through and updated mine!

Comment: this is what I was already doing - I'm looking for something that not only maps the subdomain when someone goes there in the first place, but makes all URLs display as if on that subdomain. Do you know if that's possible?  And/or can you show a further video demonstrating that this gives you the outcome I'm looking for (in which case I'll ask Google why it's not for me)?

Comment: It shouldn't be redirecting you to the google domains... you should be able to continue seeing your own domain as you navigate within the site..

Comment: thanks for the info - and you were right although my problem still isn't solved.  Please see the update on the original q. Thx.